# User management with aspnet membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, administration

Just a general question really. I have taken on the management of an application written in C# MVC that uses the asp.net membership api. With this a user can register, change their password, etc.

My application consists of two areas, administrator and user. This adminstrator's area has lots of custom admin functionality relating to the application, however has no functionality utilizing the membership api.

I want to be able to use the membership api for user management functions such as resetting a password of a user who has forgotten theirs, lock users out, etc.

Are there any resources or articles out there that delve into this aspect of using the membership api?

Any help would be appreciated :)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`MembershipUser` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx).

> The MembershipUser object is used to represent a single membership user in the membership data store. It exposes information about the membership user such as the e-mail address, and provides functionality for the membership user such as the ability to change or reset his or her password.

It has methods for [changing the password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepassword.aspx), [unlocking the user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.unlockuser.aspx) etc.

There are other resources on the MSDN, such as this one - [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very comprehensive review of most of the features of the asp.net membership system

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

search for mvc membership provider management
you'll find many examples like
http://spikes.codeplex.com/releases/view/40655